# Slim 3 prevent form resubmission

Tags: php, forms, redirect, slim

Currently after a user adds something with `/add` I will have it run a function and redirect to `/add` with a message.

```
$app->post('/add', function ($request, $response) {
    // Define and add query parameters
    $params = $request->getParams();
    new Add($params);

    // Add the new entry
    Add::newEntry();

    // Return View
    return $this->view->render($response, 'add/add.twig', [
        'add' => true
    ]);
});
```

How would I make it so after Slim redirects a user it prevents the form from submitting again upon a refresh?

Comment: Remember: HTTP is stateless. Once you've redirected after a form has been submitted, that next request doesn't "know" that the form was submitted before. It's going to treat that request as if it's a whole different user accessing it. Have you tried to use Sessions, Cookies, or the user's IP to identify whether or not they've previously submitted the form?

Comment: @maiorano84 Normally I would just redirect the user with a `header()` and everything would work as expected but now I'm trying to learn Slim which is an entirely different way of developing than I used to do.

Comment: Yes, redirecting is fine, but no matter what framework or programming language you're using, HTTP requests still won't remember the previous state after the redirect has occurred and will treat each request as a new one. In order to "remember" that the user has submitted the form and decide not to display it on the new request, you need to either create a session, cookie, database record, or at the minimum use Javascript [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or an extra request parameter (ie: &action=submitted).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found `->withHeader('Location', '/add');` on the Slim docs and it's basically the same as `header()`